# Flux Pagination

Tags: javascript, pagination, reactjs, flux

I'm anxious to see an example of pagination in a flux environment, I can't wrap my mind around how that would work. I've taken a look at [redux's example](https://github.com/gaearon/flux-react-router-example), but that's not really pagination, just a "load more" button. What I'm looking for is a way to paginate possibly millions of records (so you must use lazy loading).

Here are a few of the pitfalls I'm running into:

1) Someone could load page 20 without loading pages 1-19 (by clicking on a hyperlink, for example).

2) If someone edited a record inline, and then that record no longer satisfied the filter used to include in that list, we'll need to load more data to fill in the empty space left behind.

3) Monitoring props for changes to the page number, you'll need to load more data if that page hasn't been loaded yet.

I would love some examples that note how to overcome these pitfalls. Let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I added an example based on your title and the last sentence. To address your specific questions:

1. Of course you can load from page 20, just start from higher request params
2. Editing the record wouldn't change the state until committed right? So once you committed the edit change the filter would apply and your record would be removed if you edited the criteria that had been set by your filter
3. You would have your result set fetched further ahead as you paginated - if you clicked next it would load the next one in sequence forward, or if you clicked result start at 40 it would fetch 40-X where X is the count per fetch that you specify.  The code example I found uses 10, like most applications, so you would fetch starting at 40, but would get 40 to 50.

[This page.](http://invintus.com/2015/02/pagination-with-react-js-and-flux/)  Basically Use an Event List Store to hold the data for the child objects to access, the pagination component peice itself and finally, there's the Pagination store that

> "updates the current State of the active page and provide a function to calculate the number of pages available to the Pagination based on the Total amount of items and how many of those items are to be displayed per page"

I believe to implement this code you would need an api request with the query parameters such as search keywords and result set preferences.  This code was designed to send an api call which returns a json response that could be broken down and presented accordingly (this example does in sets of 10.)
For another working example and there are probably many others, but off hand here is [one that I know of](http://client.augur.net/markets/) personally.  This code provided below was Posted from Adam Ellsworth and credits go to him for the code:

**EventListStore.js**

```
// requires go here ...

var events = [], // Default Event listing
total  = 0,  // Default number of Available Events
start  = 0,  // Default start
end    = 9,  // Default end
amt    = 9;  // Number of Events to list per page (0-based)


processTurnPage: function (page) {
start = (page - 1) * amt;
end = start + amt;
}


var EventListStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

...

getTotal: function () {
    return total;
},
getStart: function () {
    return start;
},
getEnd: function () {
    return end;
},
getAmountPerPage: function () {
    return amt;
},

...

// emitChange, addChangeListener, removeChangeListener
});

EventListStore.dispatchToken = EventListDispatcher.register(function (payload) {

var action = payload.action,
    data   = payload.action.data;

switch (action.actionType) {
    case PageConstants.TURN_PAGE:
        processTurnPage(data);

        // Omitted:
        // Call the API to get new event data based on our new Page params

        EventListStore.emitChange();
        break;
}
});
```

**Pagination.Jsx**

```
// requires go here ...

var LIMIT = 12; // The amount of clickable <li> to show 
function getNavigation (count, per) {
/**
 * This is where we build our <li /> elements. I'm omitting our code     because
 * there are too many ways in which pagination can be displayed, and ours
 * is specific to our needs.
 *
 * What is returned below is just the gist of it.
 */

var pages = []; // what we'll store our JSX <li /> elements in.

var pages = PaginationStore.getTotalPageCount(count, per);

/**
 * Translate our 0-based pagination data to a user-friendly representation
 * by starting at 1
 */
for (var i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
    pages.push(
        <li className="page" data-value={i} key={i}>
            <a href="#">{i}</a>
        </li>
    );
}

return pages;
}

var Pagination = React.createClass({

componentDidUpdate: function (prevProps, prevState) {

    var self = this;

    $('.page').unbind().on('click', function (e) {
        var value = $(this).data('value');
        if (value != self.state.page) {
            EventViewActions.turnPage(value);
        }
    });
},


/**
 * Note here that in our EventList.jsx Component we're instantiating our
 * <Pagination /> component thusly:
 *
 * <Pagination total={this.state.total} per={this.state.amount} />
 */
render: function () {
    var navigation = getNavigation(this.props.total, this.props.per);

    return (
        <ul>
            {navigation}
        </ul>
    );
}
});
```

**Pagination.jsx**

```
// requires ...

var _page = 1; // Default page

updatePage: function (page) {
console.log('changing page: ' + _page + ' -> ' + page);
_page = page;
}

var PaginationStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

getPage: function () {
    return _page;
},
getTotalPageCount: function (total, per) {

    var pages = total - 1;

    if (pages > 0) {
        if (per < pages) {
            return Math.ceil(pages / per);
        }
        return 1; // only one page of items
    } else {
        return 0; // no items
    }
},

...
});

PaginationStore.dispatchToken = EventListDispatcher.register(function (payload) {

var action = payload.action,
    data   = payload.action.data;

switch (action.actionType) {
    case PageConstants.TURN_PAGE:
        updatePage(data)
        PaginationStore.emitChange();
        break;

}
});
```